# How to hide code blocks

Tags: support, feature-request

I believe one of the reasons people use code snippets incorrectly is because of long code. I can't find a way to make code blocks minimizable like snippets. You might argue that *long code is not a minimal example!* but in some cases, a long piece of code is required. I think having such a feature will discourage people from linking to off-site hosting pages. Is this feature already available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make a question readable, split a long code block into many smaller code blocks and insert non-code between them. Such non-code should explain what the next part of code does and why it is included in the question.

So I don't think such a feature is necessary or a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

> *" I can't find a way to make code locks minimizable like snippets. You might be going Long code is not a minimal example! but in some cases, **a long piece of code is required**."*

No! The real point is, we ***really*** expect from the OP to narrow down their code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If that needs more debugging to get there, this is an effort expected from the OP's side.

Answer (score -1):

In the case of the Code Review Stack Exchange, larger code blocks can be warranted.

In that case it *would* be convenient if one could somehow squash the code blocks.

Comment: Then this suggestion should be made on code review's [meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/) or on [meta.se], but probably not on MSO.

Comment: This answer isn't relevant to SO, though, since SO isn't Code Review.

Comment: Code review questions _are_ on topic on SO, [see also](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). Of course if you have a 1000-line project you want to get reviewed you're indeed probably better off asking on CR. Still, nobody should pretend that code review questions are automatically off-topic here.